# How to create a setuptools sdist .tar.gz package from a Conda project?

Tags: python, conda, setuptools, google-cloud-vertex-ai, sdist

I have a PyTorch training project where dependencies are managed using [conda](https://conda.io). I need to package my project as a `setuptools` [software distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html) (sdist) in a `.tar.gz` file so that I can run it as a custom job in Google Cloud Platform's Vertex.AI Training service.

I've found an official guide that explains [how to generate a bdist package using Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/build-without-recipe.html) but I don't think I can use that in Vertex.AI.

**Is there a Conda command for generating an sdist distribution? Or are there any other tools I can use to get this done automatically?**

*Please note:* I know I can manually recreate the list of dependencies in my setuptools `setup.py` file but I would rather not do that because manually maintaining two copies of the same list could link to sync issues and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python setuptools to achieve it. On vertex ai documentation about [using Setuptools to build a source distribution to use with Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container#create_a_source_distribution) there is a complete guide on how to achieve it.

Its provide you with this steps to consider when dealing with your own packages:

- Follow the instructions on [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container#before_you_begin) and [Application structure](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container#structure)
- Create your setup.
- Add dependencies ( Could be Python or Custom dependencies - If any )
- Setup Python Modules ( If any )
- Upload your source distribution to Cloud Storage

**Note**: Vertex AI suggest some alternatives to it as described on [Alternatives to creating a source distribution](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container#alternatives_to_creating_a_source_distribution).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in describing what I need. I am already managing dependencies using Conda. I need a way to include these dependencies (as well as my source code) in the sdist. Maintaining a duplicate list of the same dependencies in `setup.py` is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Have you check the [alternatives](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-python-pre-built-container#alternatives_to_creating_a_source_distribution)? because that is what vertex ai is suggesting. I don't think of a built-in feature to work like you suggest but i think it can be requested on the [issue tracker](https:///issuetracker.google.com/new?component=958003&template=1525607).

Comment: or maybe it's something like a [custom-prediction-routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines).

Comment: Thank you @betjens. I am familiar with the alternatives. They involve wrapping my training task in a container and that makes the process of uploading it to GCS slower in my experience. custom-prediction-routines are not relevant because my code is for training, not for prediction.